# Android config firebase realtime database rule for normal user access

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My application has integrated Chat feature using Firebase Realtime DB for storing chat content.
Recently, I received the email has content:

> [Firebase] Your Realtime Database ***** has insecure rules

My app's using authentication by server-side without integrating Firebase Authen. So, if I set the read/write rules to `false`, the normal user can not chat.
How to resolve this issue? Thanks!

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making read and write public is not a good idea . For server side you are good to go with admin sdk. But form client end you should use some kind of authentication. You can use [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/where-to-start) available with credentials, Anonymous authentication or [custom token authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). Rules will be like :-

```
{
 "rules": {
".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid !== null",
".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid !== null"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the user sign-in before accessing the database, change the rules to..

```
".read" : "auth != null",
".write" : "auth != null"
```

This will let the, authenticated users to access the database.

Comment: As the description from my question, my application is only use authentication by server-side, so there is no more firebase authentication in my application. And I can not use that rule configuration